# How to "pipe" console values into interactive Windows PowerShell command (to make it non-interactive)

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, interactive, non-interactive

Does Windows PowerShell have anything that's similar to piping user-supplied values into interactive Unix/Linux bash commands to make them run non-interactive?

What I mean is something like this:

https://www.igorkromin.net/index.php/2017/04/12/invoking-interactive-shell-scripts-non-interactively

I need to supply values directly via PowerShell instead of letting the user type them on the console.

What I mean is *not* something that would be equivalent to xargs in bash, as that would only allow me to supplant command line parameters. For the specific command that I have in mind, default values can be specified on the command line, but are not suitable for the specific task. There are not any other parameters that can be given on the command line - values other than default are normally given by user input.

The only thing I tried out was similar to how you would do it in bash:

echo VALUE | CMD

This didn't work as the command still asked for user input on the console.

Comment: It should be similar if it works in unix.  `echo y | command`.  It depends on the specific case.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.